# How to store an ordered set of documents in MongoDB without using a capped collection

Tags: mongodb, sorting

What's a good way to store a set of documents in MongoDB where order is important?  I need to easily insert documents at an arbitrary position and possibly reorder them later.

I could assign each item an increasing number and sort by that, or I could sort by `_id`, but I don't know how I could then insert another document in between other documents.  Say I want to insert something between an element with a `sequence` of `5` and an element with a `sequence` of `6`?

My first guess would be to increment the `sequence` of all of the following elements so that there would be space for the new element using a query something like `db.items.update({"sequence":{$gte:6}}, {$inc:{"sequence":1}})`.  My limited understanding of Database Administration tells me that a query like that would be slow and generally a bad idea, but I'm happy to be corrected.

I guess I could set the new element's `sequence` to `5.5`, but I think that would get messy rather quickly. (Again, correct me if I'm wrong.)

I could use a capped collection, which has a guaranteed order, but then I'd run into issues if I needed to grow the collection. (Yet again, I might be wrong about that one too.)

I could have each document contain a reference to the next document, but that would require a query for each item in the list.  (You'd get an item, push it onto the results array, and get another item based on the `next` field of the current item.)  Aside from the obvious performance issues, I would also not be able to pass a sorted mongo cursor to my `{#each}` spacebars block expression and let it live update as the database changed. (I'm using the [Meteor](http://meteor.com) full-stack javascript framework.)

I know that everything has it's advantages and disadvantages, and I might just have to use one of the options listed above, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do things.

Answer (score 8):

Based on your requirement, one of the approaches could be to design your schema, in such a way that each document *has the capability* to hold more than one document and in itself act as a *capped container*.

```
{
  "_id":Number,
  "doc":Array
}
```

Each document in the collection will act as a *capped container*, and the documents will be stored as array in the `doc` field. The `doc` field being an array, will maintain the order of insertion.
You can limit the number of documents to `n`. So the `_id` field of each container document will be incremental by `n`, indicating the number of documents a container document can hold.

By doing these you **avoid** adding `extra fields` to the document, `extra indices`, `unnecessary sorts`.

### Inserting the very first record

i.e when the collection is empty.

```
var record = {"name" : "first"};
db.col.insert({"_id":0,"doc":[record]});
```

### Inserting subsequent records

- Identify the last container document's `_id`, and the `number` of
  documents it holds.
- If the number of documents it holds is less than `n`, then **update** the
  container document with the new document, else **create** a new container
  document.

Say, that each `container document` can hold `5` documents at most,and we want to insert a new document.

```
var record = {"name" : "newlyAdded"};

// using aggregation, get the _id of the last inserted container, and the 
// number of record it currently holds.
db.col.aggregate( [ {
    $group : {
        "_id" : null,
        "max" : {
            $max : "$_id"
        },
        "lastDocSize" : {
            $last : "$doc"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        "currentMaxId" : "$max",
        "capSize" : {
            $size : "$lastDocSize"
        },
        "_id" : 0
    }
// once obtained, check if you need to update the last container or 
// create a new container and insert the document in it.
} ]).forEach( function(check) {
    if (check.capSize < 5) {
        print("updating");
        // UPDATE
        db.col.update( {
            "_id" : check.currentMaxId
        }, {
            $push : {
                "doc" : record
            }
        });
    } else {
        print("inserting");
        //insert
        db.col.insert( {
            "_id" : check.currentMaxId + 5,
            "doc" : [ record ]
        });
    }
})
```

Note that the `aggregation`, runs on the server side and is very efficient, also note that the `aggregation` would return you a **document** rather than a **cursor** in versions `previous to 2.6`. So you would need to modify the above code to just select from a single document rather than iterating a cursor.

### Inserting a new document in between documents

Now, if you would like to insert a new document between documents `1` and `2`, we know that the document should fall inside the container with `_id=0` and should be placed in the `second` position in the `doc` array of that container.

so, we make use of the `$each` and `$position` operators for inserting into specific positions.

```
var record = {"name" : "insertInMiddle"};

db.col.update(
{
    "_id" : 0
}, {
    $push : {
        "doc" : {
            $each : [record],
            $position : 1
        }
    }
}
);
```

### Handling Over Flow

Now, we need to take care of documents `overflowing` in each `container`, say we insert a new document in between, in container with `_id=0`. If the container already has `5` documents, we need to `move the last document to the next container` and do so till all the containers hold documents within their capacity, if required at last we need to create a container to hold the overflowing documents.

This complex operation **should** be done on the **server side**. To handle this, we can create a script such as the one below and `register` it with mongodb.

```
db.system.js.save( {
    "_id" : "handleOverFlow",
    "value" : function handleOverFlow(id) {
        var currDocArr = db.col.find( {
            "_id" : id
        })[0].doc;
        print(currDocArr);
        var count = currDocArr.length;
        var nextColId = id + 5;
        // check if the collection size has exceeded
    if (count <= 5)
        return;
    else {
        // need to take the last doc and push it to the next capped 
    // container's array
    print("updating collection: " + id);
    var record = currDocArr.splice(currDocArr.length - 1, 1);
    // update the next collection
    db.col.update( {
        "_id" : nextColId
    }, {
        $push : {
            "doc" : {
                $each : record,
                $position : 0
            }
        }
    });
    // remove from original collection
    db.col.update( {
        "_id" : id
    }, {
        "doc" : currDocArr
    });
    // check overflow for the subsequent containers, recursively.
    handleOverFlow(nextColId);
}
}
```

So that `after every insertion in between` , we can invoke this `function` by passing the container id, `handleOverFlow(containerId)`.

### Fetching all the records in order

Just use the `$unwind` operator in the `aggregate pipeline`.

```
db.col.aggregate([{$unwind:"$doc"},{$project:{"_id":0,"doc":1}}]);
```

### Re-Ordering Documents

You can store each document in a capped container with an "_id" field:

```
.."doc":[{"_id":0,","name":"xyz",...}..]..
```

Get hold of the "doc" array of the capped container of which you want
   to reorder items.

```
var docArray = db.col.find({"_id":0})[0];
```

Update their ids so that after sorting the order of the item will change.

Sort the array based on their _ids.

```
docArray.sort( function(a, b) {
    return a._id - b._id;
});
```

update the capped container back, with the new doc array.

But then again, everything boils down to which approach is feasible and suits your requirement best.

Coming to your questions:

> *What's a good way to store a set of documents in MongoDB where order is important?I need to easily insert documents at an arbitrary
>   position and possibly reorder them later.*

Documents as Arrays.

> *Say I want to insert something between an element with a sequence of 5 and an element with a sequence of 6?*

use the `$each` and `$position` operators in the `db.collection.update()` function as depicted in my answer.

> *My limited understanding of Database Administration tells me that a
>   query like that would be slow and generally a bad idea, but I'm happy
>   to be corrected.*

Yes. It would impact the performance, unless the collection has very less data.

> *I could use a capped collection, which has a guaranteed order, but then I'd run into issues if I needed to grow the collection. (Yet
>   again, I might be wrong about that one too.)*

Yes. With Capped Collections, you may lose data.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for taking the time to write up such a detailed description.  One question: why do I need to put a limit to the number of documents that a container document can hold?  Why can't I put _all_ the documents in the array of one parent document?.

Comment: @BonsaiOak - mongodb limits the size of a document to 16 mb. Moreover, dumping all the documents in a single container would lead to out of memory issues when you run some aggregate operators on them. Fixing and limiting the the number of documents in a container helps you identify, documents based on their index. Eg. It is always guaranteed that the 4th document will be in the 1st container and the 6th doc in the 2nd container, when the cap size is 5. Knowing this before hand in your application layer, reduces a lot of coding effort.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the detailed answer. Also, the approach of creating a "doc containing a bunch of docs" is quite interesting.

Comment: It's worth noting that Mongodb does not support atomic interactions with arrays within arrays. Regardless of the major speed, maintenance, and developer bottleneck that this style will perpetuate, you will run into some major walls as your subdocuments and sub-subdocuments start becoming more complex and you lose the ability to insert new data or atomically get, put, or delete data

Answer (score 2):

An `_id` field in MongoDB is a unique, indexed key similar to a primary key in relational databases. If there is an inherent order in your documents, ideally you should be able to associate a unique key to each document, with the key value reflecting the order. So while preparing your document for insertion, explicitly add an `_id` field as this key (if you do not, mongo creates it automatically with a BSON objectid).

As far as retrieving the results are concerned, [**MongoDB does not guarantee the order of return documents unless you explicitly use `.sort()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#result-ordering) . If you do not use `.sort()`, the results are usually returned in natural order (order of insertion).Again, there is no guarantee on this behavior.

I'd advise you to override `_id` with your order while inserting, and use a sort while retrieving. Since `_id` is a necessary and auto-indexed entity, you will not be wasting any space defining a sort key, and storing the index for it.

Comment: How would I insert an item into the middle of the list with this system?

Comment: I assume you mean inserting a new item and keeping the order intact. That logic ideally should be handled by your application. If you are using numbers as keys, use a new number between the two.If using alphabet like a,b etc, you can use a0, a1 etc.As I said, your application knows the inherent order, and the application should be the one to provide the logic for keeping order.

Answer (score 1):

For abitrary sorting of any collection, you'll need a field to sort it on. I call mine "sequence".

```
schema:
{
 _id: ObjectID,
 sequence: Number,
 ...
}

db.items.ensureIndex({sequence:1});

db.items.find().sort({sequence:1})
```

Comment: How would I then go about reordering items?  I'm editing my question to clarify this.

Comment: I'd use the classic BASIC code ordering trick of having your sequence numbers be multiples of 100. Then you could stick 99 items in between two existing items without having to resort all of them. It isn't perfect, but probably would work depending on the size of your set.

Comment: having your sequence in multiples of 100 so you can stick 99 items between them is not scalable and definitely should not be in a production environment. A good example of technical debt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some general sorting database answers that may be relevant:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195308/storing-a-re-orderable-list-in-a-database/369754

I suggest going with `Floating point` solution - adding a `position` column:

Use a floating-point number for the position column.
You can then reorder the list changing only the position column in the "moved" row.
If your user wants to position "red" after "blue" but before "yellow" Then you just need to calculate

`red.position = ((yellow.position - blue.position) / 2) + blue.position`

After a few re-positions in the same place (Cuttin in half every time) - you might reach a wall - it's better that if you reach a certain threshold - to resort the list.

When retrieving it you can simply say `col.sort()` to get it sorted and no need for any client-side code (Like in the case of a Linked list solution)