# How to insert an element to the middle of an array with MongoDBv2.4/minimongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm writing a music organization app with the latest version of [Meteor](http://meteor.com) (A new web framework.). I think that the best way to store playlists is to put each playlist in a document and put the items of the playlist in array inside the document. It looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "a very cool playlist"
  "items: [
    {"audioFileID": 144}
    {"audioFileID": 443}
    {"audioFileID": 035}
    {"audioFileID": 442}
  ]
}
```

My problem is that that minimongo (Meteor's pure javascript MongoDB implementation) only supports MongoDB 2.4.  That means I can't use the `$position` operator to insert a playlist element in the middle of the playlist.  What's the best way to get around this?  I can't believe that nobody had a way to insert items into the middle of an array before MongoDB 2.6.  Or maybe there's a way to easily patch minimongo.

Comment: You could probably do something with using the [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#sort) modifier on a `$push`, but you'd have to add a field to your elements to sort on.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I guess that means that I'm down to the options explained to me in [my other question about ordering documents within collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220879)

Comment: Unless it is a client-only collection, you could do it with meteor method on the server (though this will cost the latency compensation)

Comment: @RuneJeppesen Are you saying that I could use MongoDB 2.6 on the server, and thus have direct access to the extra operators?

Comment: BonsaiOak yes. Though I am not sure what version the server uses :-\

Comment: @RuneJeppesen The latest version of Meteor uses MongodB v2.4.9.  However, I understand that it's possible to point Meteor at any MongoDB server, so I don't see why I couldn't point it to a server running v2.6.*  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Worth a shot :-) I have not tried it